# Retrieve a Customized Report to many Users

Tags: active-directory, ssrs-2008, data-warehouse, publish-subscribe

Goal:
Every user, who has a AD account shall retrieve a customized and personal report, that is filtrerad data of their personal name, sent to their email account.

Problem:
Based on my searching you can send same report to many AD users by using data-driven subscription in SSRS report server. Please look at the picture.

My request is to enable to filtrate the dataset, containing the list of data, that user can read their own data only, not the others. The list of user is based on data from AD account.

```
Is it possible to do it? If yes, how to do it?
```

Information:
*You are enable to retrieve their e-mail that is based on their AD account.
*Data source is SSAS.
*Using SQL server 2008 R2.
*The database is a data mart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create two Datasets:

Dataset 1 Employee Information

```
Select 
        Your Fields here for the report
    From your Table(s) Where employeeid = @Employeeid
```

Dataset 2 Filtered information

```
Select employeeid
From Table – This should be the same table as from the Dataset 1
```

Create your report based on Dataset 1
Set a filter on the Report: Use Dataset 2 as the available values for the Parameter (@Employeeid) of the report.

This will give you the filtered information that you need in your report.

You can then use this link to set up your data subscription email: [Creating a Parameter Subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89197b9b-7502-4fe2-bea3-ed7943eebf3b)

Hope that helps.